# Subcomplexes with homotopy type of a sphere in complexes with homotopy type of a wedge of spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-complexes

Suppose $X$ is a finite $d$-dimensional simplicial complex which is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of at least two $d$-spheres. Does $X$ contain a subcomplex which is homotopy equivalent to a single $d$-sphere?

Comment: Just looking at graphs (d=1) one might check the following approach: Claim1: There is a d-simplex such that removing that simplex changes the $H_d$. Claim2: The complement of such a simplex does the job. Are both claims true or is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EDIT: Wow, I worked a lot harder than necessary. I've added a simplified version of this proof. The original is at the bottom.

Let $A = S^1$, with fundamental group the free group $F$ on a generator $x$. Consider the elements
$$
\begin{align*}
a &= x^6\\
b &= x^{10}\\
c &= x^{15}
\end{align*}
$$
in $F$, and use them as attaching maps: attach three 2-dimensional cells to $A$ to construct a space $B$.

Here are some properties of $B$.

- It is simply-connected. The fundamental group of $B$ is
  $$
  \langle x \mid x^6, x^{10}, x^{15}\rangle
  $$
  and this group is trivial.
- It has homology $\Bbb Z^2$ in degree $2$, $\Bbb Z$ in degree 0, and 0 elsewhere. You can see this from the cellular chain complex $0 \to \Bbb Z^3 \to \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z \to 0$ for computing $H_* B$, using the fact that $H_1 B = [\pi_1 B]_{ab} = 0$.
- As a result, $\pi_2(B) = \Bbb Z^2$ by the Hurewicz theorem and there is a map $S^2 \vee S^2 \to B$ inducing an isomorphism on $H_*$. By the Whitehead theorem, this means that $B$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee S^2$.

I claim that no proper subcomplex of $B$ is homotopy equivalent to a $2$-sphere because any proper subcomplex that has some 2-dimensional cells is not simply-connected.

The only possibility is for such a subcomplex to take the $1$-cell and some assortment of the $2$-cells. However, taking any two of the 2-cells doesn't give you something simply-connected, because you only get these possible fundamental groups:

- $\langle x \mid x^{10}, x^{15}\rangle \cong \Bbb Z/5$
- $\langle x \mid x^6, x^{15}\rangle \cong \Bbb Z/3$
- $\langle x \mid x^6, x^{10}\rangle \cong \Bbb Z/2$

(Using fewer than two of the $2$-cells gives you an even larger fundamental group.)

---

The original example had $A = S^1 \vee S^1$, with fundamental group the free group $F$ on generators $x$ and $y$, and used
$$
\begin{align*}
a &= x^2\\
b &= y^3\\
c &= (xy)^5\\
d &= xyx^{-1}y^{-1}
\end{align*}
$$
as attaching maps for four 2-dimensional cells.

Comment: Very nice counterexample, thank you!